# Pentaho cannot connect to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I downloaded the latest Pentaho version (v8.3) from [here](https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/products/big-data-integration-analytics/pentaho-trial-download.html) and successfully connected to PostgreSQL.

When I try to connect to SQL Server 2017:

[image]

and hit the **TEST** button, nothing happens.

After I did a re-search, I tried different solutions but nothing happened.

I downloaded the latest **jdbc driver**(got it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) ([direct download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58505))), and copy the jar files into:

```
C:\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\lib
```

Also copied the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` from the Microsoft JDBC Driver folder and pasted it here:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib
C:\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\libswt
```

And on each change I've made, I've re-started the Pentaho, but nothing either.

I've checked the SQL Server settings, and TCP/IP is enabled, as well as the mixed authentication.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong, and how to resolve this.

Comment: If you're connecting to a named instance will it be on port 1433?

Answer (score 1):

After doing every combinations with the drivers, this is what worked:

1. I've downloaded (sqljdbc_7.4 driver -> [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58505))
2. Extract the files
3. Copied **`sqljdbc_auth.dll`** from

   `sqljdbc_7.4\enu\auth\x64` to

   `C:\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\libswt\win64`

   also

   **`sqljdbc_auth.dll`** from

   `sqljdbc_7.4\enu\auth\x86` to

   `C:\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\libswt\win32`
4. Copied **`mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar`** from

   `sqljdbc_7.4\enu` to

   `C:\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\lib`

Answer (score 1):

Add `trustservercertificate` attribute `true` under options

[image: Pentoho --> Options]